# Azure Storage account back up loop

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-python-sdk

I hope somebody can help to understand and solve this `small` issue I am facing by following the best approach.

I have a huge list of storage accounts, over 54 of them. Every single storage account have multiple blobs and table underneath it. And I would like to make a backup of each storage account to another storage account.

So I started writing the backup code, which what it does, its just a loop over a specific storage blobs and tables, make a copy and paste them into another storage account.

This is the code for blob and table loop

```
from typing import Container
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService,ListGenerator
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient, BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient
from azure.storage.blob import ResourceTypes, AccountSasPermissions
from azure.storage.blob import generate_account_sas    
from datetime import date
from datetime import *

today = str(date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d"))
print(today)




#================================ SOURCE ===============================
# Source Client
connection_string = '' # The connection string for the source container
account_key = '' # The account key for the source container
# source_container_name = 'newblob' # Name of container which has blob to be copied
table_service_out = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')
table_service_in = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')

# Create client
client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string) 




client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
all_containers = client.list_containers(include_metadata=True)
for container in all_containers:
    # Create sas token for blob
    sas_token = generate_account_sas(
        account_name = client.account_name,
        account_key = account_key, 
        resource_types = ResourceTypes(object=True, container=True),
        permission= AccountSasPermissions(read=True,list=True),
        # start = datetime.now(),
        expiry = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=4) # Token valid for 4 hours
    )

    
    print("==========================")
    print(container['name'], container['metadata'])
    
    # print("==========================")
    container_client = client.get_container_client(container.name)
    # print(container_client)
    blobs_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    for blob in blobs_list:
        # Create blob client for source blob
        source_blob = BlobClient(
        client.url,
        container_name = container['name'],
        blob_name = blob.name,
        credential = sas_token
    )
        target_connection_string = ''
        target_account_key = ''
        source_container_name = container['name']
        target_blob_name = blob.name
        target_destination_blob = container['name'] + today
        print(target_blob_name)
        # print(blob.name)
        target_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(target_connection_string)
        try:
            container_client = target_client.create_container(target_destination_blob)
            new_blob = target_client.get_blob_client(target_destination_blob, target_blob_name)
            new_blob.start_copy_from_url(source_blob.url)
            print("COPY TO")
            print(f"TRY: saving blob {target_blob_name} into {target_destination_blob} ")
        except:
            # Create new blob and start copy operation.
            new_blob = target_client.get_blob_client(target_destination_blob, target_blob_name)
            new_blob.start_copy_from_url(source_blob.url)
            print("COPY TO")
            print(f"EXCEPT: saving blob {target_blob_name} into {target_destination_blob} ")
        

#query 100 items per request, in case of consuming too much menory load all data in one time
query_size = 100

#save data to storage2 and check if there is lefted data in current table，if yes recurrence
def queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(tb_name,resp_data:ListGenerator ,table_out:TableService,table_in:TableService,query_size:int):
    for item in resp_data:
        #remove etag and Timestamp appended by table service
        del item.etag
        del item.Timestamp
        print("instet data:" + str(item) + "into table:"+ tb_name)
        table_in.insert_or_replace_entity(tb_name,item)
    if resp_data.next_marker:
        data = table_out.query_entities(table_name=tb_name,num_results=query_size,marker=resp_data.next_marker)
        queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(tb_name,data,table_out,table_in,query_size)


tbs_out = table_service_out.list_tables()
print(tbs_out)

for tb in tbs_out:
    table = tb.name + today
    print(target_connection_string)
    #create table with same name in storage2
    table_service_in.create_table(table_name=table, fail_on_exist=False)
    #first query
    data = table_service_out.query_entities(tb.name,num_results=query_size)
    queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(table,data,table_service_out,table_service_in,query_size)
```

But as you can see in my code, I have

```
# Source Client
connection_string = '' # The connection string for the source container
account_key = '' # The account key for the source container
# source_container_name = 'newblob' # Name of container which has blob to be copied
table_service_out = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')
table_service_in = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')
```

Which they are hard coded connection strings and keys.

on the other hand, I am using `azure bicep` to create all the backup storages where I can backup all the content from the previous code.

But here is my blocker and I cannot think about a correct way to make this dynamic.

In my first code (the copy) I have hard coded variables, which mean I have to copy and paste the connection string from each storage account >> run the script >> wait for it to finish >> start over with the next storage.

What I would like to do, is maybe to have a sort of mapping between storage A and StorageBackupA, where I can list all my connection string and run the script only once so that it can loop over all those connection string and copy the blobs etc to the backup storage assigned.

I was considering different approach, such as 2 lists, one for StorageA and one for backup, or dictionary, but I am having hard time to figure out the best way to develop this step.

I hope my description is clear enough and please if you need more info do not hesitate to ask.

Thank you very much for any help you can provide